# How to find all members of loaded assemblies that implement an interface and execute method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have an MVC application that has separate areas as individual projects (modular architecture). Each of these projects have specific controllers that implement an interface. So, i can get all the loaded assemblies that implement that interface using this code...

```
var type = typeof(IAreaRegistration);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p))
                .Where(i => i.IsInterface == false)
                .ToList();
```

My question is, how can I execute an interface method on each type found from the query without using ***Activator.CreateInstance()*** which essentially loads a new instance of that type into memory? I have the following code which works, but like I said, it creates a new instance and I don't think it's the best way.

```
foreach (var item in types)
{
    var cls = Activator.CreateInstance(item) as IAreaRegistration;
    // call interface members here...
}
```